# How JNE work in Ollydbg?

Tags: assembly

I have a question about JNE.
I use ollydbg and ReverseMe tutorial.

In **JNE** condition, the zero flag is equal to **1**. and it mean the arithmetic result is **zero**. Right?

The **Z=1** meaning the condition is true and it want to jump to Error message???
and If i change the **zero flag** to **0** **(Z=0)**, it mean false? and ignore the Error message??

JNE = Jump If not Equal. So whats that mean? if not equal to .. ? What does it compare to?

i confused ...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNE is an alias for JNZ because the CMP instruction will set ZF to 1 if the two values being compared are equal. So you can read it as “jump if **not zero flag**”, or “jump if ZF is not set”, or “jump if ZF is 0”.

In your specific case, the jump will be taken if `eax` is *not equal* to -1.

Comment: So bases on CMP eax,-1 , it's equal ? eax is fffff !

Comment: @Jason it’s checking for equality but jumping if *not* equal

Comment: Thank you. is there any source to understand assembly codes?

Comment: Yes, for example Intel Assembly Manual.